# How to make jemalloc to use transparent huge pages?

Tags: memory-management, malloc, huge-pages, jemalloc

I want jemalloc to use transparent huge pages.

My environment parameter are as follows:

```
echo $MALLOC_CONF
"thp:always,prof:false,prof_active:false,trust_madvise:false"
```

However, kernel THP were not enabled. When I set `/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled` to `madvise` and execute the command `grep Huge /proc/meminfo`, the field `AnonHugePages` did not increase. As a comparison, when `/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled` is set to `always`, the field `AnonHugePages` increases significantly.

**I examined the parameter passed to kernel `do_madvise()` [function](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14/source/mm/madvise.c#L1127) and found that there are no function calls in the system that use `MADV_HUGEPAGE` [parameter](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/mman-common.h#L62), which differs from [the document](https://jemalloc.net/jemalloc.3.html#opt.thp):**

> The "always" setting enables transparent hugepage for all user memory mappings with MADV_HUGEPAGE

Moreover, with current `MALLOC_CONF`, jemalloc report message of `stderr F <jemalloc>: Malformed conf string`. I tried with method from [this issue](https://github.com/tikv/tikv/issues/10150), but didn't help.

How can jemalloc use THP without recompiling and affecting other processes?